# flutter SingleChildScrollView inside Slidable

Tags: scroll, flutter, overflow, screen-size

If have a flutter page with a list view which shall display data. When the user slides the record, it shall show more details about the data. This works perfect with a slidable and IconSlide action. My problem starts when the data is larger as the screen. If I am doing nothing, I will get an overflow (yellow / black stripes) on the right border.

So my thought was yo have a SingleChildScrollView. So the user slides to te left and the data is shown, and next to the data the button for the details action will be presented.

What I got with the source code below. The Slidable works if the data fits on the screen. The button is correctly shown. When the data exceeds the size of the screen, the user can slide and the data is shown. However, the button will not appear.

Has anybody an idea how to solve this?

This example has the same behaviour. At a certain row the DETAILS icons is gone.

add flutter_slidable: "^0.4.9" as dependency in pub spec.yaml

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_slidable/flutter_slidable.dart';

    List<int> fakeData = List();

    void main() async {

      for (int i=0 ; i < 100 ; i++)
        fakeData.add(i*5);

      runApp( MaterialApp(
        home: MyHomePage(title: "Example")
      ));
    }

    class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

      final String title;

      @override
      _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
    }

    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

      Widget build(BuildContext context) {

        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
            title: Text(
              "Example",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)
            ),
          ),
          body: ListView.builder (
            itemCount:  100,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                _showCard(index)  // Toon logboek regel
            )
        );
      }

      // De kaart met de vlucht info
      Widget _showCard(int index) {
        return 
          Card(
            elevation: 1.5,
            child: _showDetails(index)
          );
      }

      // Toon de basis informatie 
      Widget _showDetails(index) {
        return
          Slidable(
            delegate: SlidableDrawerDelegate(),        
            direction: Axis.horizontal,
            secondaryActions: <Widget>[
              new IconSlideAction(
                caption: 'Details',
                color: Colors.grey,
                icon: Icons.more_horiz,
                onTap: () => 
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                      // action to be done
                    ),
                  ),
              ),
            ],
            child: _content(index)
          );
      }

    // hier gaat het om
      Widget _content(int index) {
        return
          SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget> [
                SizedBox(
                  width:25, 
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 12.0, 
                    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                    child: Text(
                      (index+1).toString(),
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13.0)
                    )
                  )
                ),
                Padding (padding: EdgeInsets.all(3)), 
                Container(
                  height: 40,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, 
                    children: <Widget>[
                      _data(index)
                    ]
                  )
                )
              ]
            )
        );  
      }

      Widget _data(int index) {
        return
         Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              border: new Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent)
            ),
            child: SizedBox(width: 1.0*fakeData[index], height: 25, child: Text(fakeData[index].toString()))
          );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Post an image of the result, and code that we will be able to past to try it out will be helpful.

Comment: The code is updated, you can just paste it and will see that it goes wrong at a certain row. Which row is depended on your screen size